# UIAlertView:Dismiss UIAlertView on click of out side the alert box

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

Hi I am new to Xcode n objective-C need help on this one.
I have a no button UIAlertView, which gets dismissed on click on itself.But i want to dismiss it only on click of outside the alert box not inside. Thanks

```
 //generating the alertview with no button

 +(void) showAlertNoButtons:(NSString*)title text:(NSString*)text{

    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:title message:text
                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

   UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self
                                    action:@selector(dismissAlert:)];

   alertView.delegate=self;
   [alertView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
   [alertView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
   [alertView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

  [alertView show];
 }
   //
  +(void)dismissAlert:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
    {
      UIAlertView* alertView =(UIAlertView *)gesture.view;
      [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260562/ios-how-to-dismiss-uialertview-with-one-tap-anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated`

When you tap anywhere else

This piece of code will handle your tap

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:index animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: `[self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES]` if you don't want the tap to perform any of the alert's functions while dismissing it.