# How to dismiss UIAlertView in both iOS 7 & iOS 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

How to dismiss uialertview(default) when click on out side. Here I have set the uialert with only one button (OK). Intend for implement this alert, if user seen free offer pack from this uialertview and he want to access his free pack offer by clicking the OK button in uialertview. Otherwise if he doesn't want to access his free offer pack at this time the user can tap the outside of uialert view and the alertview dismissed it.

Kindly give suggestion for how dismiss uialertview from out side clicking.

```
    offeredAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                         message:strMessage
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    [offeredAlert setTag:10002];
    [offeredAlert show];

    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *tempStr;
    if(alertView.tag == 10001)
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            tempStr = @"payable";
            [self dietPackPurchaseAPI:id_Pack type:tempStr];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is not supported by `UIAlertView` you will have to create your own alert view.

Comment: @rckoenes thank you for reply. U mean create the custom UIAlertview ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a full custom alert view.

Comment: see this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260562/ios-how-to-dismiss-uialertview-with-one-tap-anywhere