# Dismiss UIAlertControllerStyleAlert UIAlertController by tapping outside

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

As everyone's aware, `UIAlertView` is deprecated now and Apple wants us to use the new `UIAlertController` with the style `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`. However, using the `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` you cannot trigger the `UIAlertAction` with style `UIAlertActionStyleCancel` by tapping outside the alert view.

Does anyone know of a way to dismiss the alert view by tapping outside of it?

Cheers

Comment: `UIAlertView` didn't support that either. You always need to tap one of the buttons.

Comment: Oh really? I wonder why then that sort of behaviour is so ingrained into alerts for me. Would you have a suggestion as to how I could achieve that?

Comment: On the iPad, `UIActionSheet` could be dismissed by tapping outside, but that has never been the case (on any iOS devices) for `UIAlertView`.

Comment: I see. It seems that is also the case on iPhones with UIActionSheet. I've just tried some hacky things to achieve tap-to-dismiss on an Alert style such as adding a tap gesture on the presenting view controller, but to no avail.

Comment: May be you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260562/ios-how-to-dismiss-uialertview-with-one-tap-anywhere

Answer (score 2):

You can add a separate cancel action with style **UIAlertActionStyleCancel** for the alertViewController so that when user taps outside, you would get the callback.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"A Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
     // Called when user taps outside
 }]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self button];

}

- (void) button {
    UIButton * AlertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [AlertButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    AlertButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - 50 , (self.view.frame.size.height/2) - 25, 100, 50);
    [AlertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Alert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:AlertButton];
}

- (void)Alert {
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"Alert Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [self presentViewController: alert animated: YES completion:^{ alert.view.superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES; [alert.view.superview addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(DismissAlertByTab)]]; }];
}

- (void)DismissAlertByTab
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
}
```